# Iteration in while loop runs and ends without taking inputs?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, stringstream, deque

I want to split string and store it in `result` deque according to current input and do this again `while (count-- > 0)`

count = 3 in this case.

input string : **abc def ghi**

```
   while (count-- > 0){
    cout << " start of while loop" << endl;
    deque<string> result;
    string str2;
    cin >> str2;
    istringstream iss(str2);
    for(string s; iss >> s; ){
      result.push_back(s);
    } 
    cout << "result.size() " << result.size() << endl;
    }
   }
```

**Problem** : result size remains 1 and while loop runs 3 times automatically.

**Todo**     : result size should be 3 in 1 iteration

**Output :**

```
start of while loop
abc def ghi
result.size() 1
start of while loop
result.size() 1
start of while loop     
result.size() 1
```

I should have been able to take inputs 3 times, but while loop runs 3 time automatically without taking inputs and ends.
Why is it happening ?

Comment: Are you sure the deque is inside the loop?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you have, but remember that the input operator `>>` reads *space separated* input. No need for the inner loop. Unless you want to [read one line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) at a time and *then* separate it?

Comment: but  why while loop does not take inputs ?

Comment: Think about *scope*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
  while (count-- > 0){
    cout << " start of while loop" << endl;
    deque<string> result;  // result created inside loop
```

you want this

```
  deque<string> result; // result created outside loop
  while (count-- > 0){
    cout << " start of while loop" << endl;
```

otherwise, result is being recreated for each iteration of the loop.

Also, it sounds like you are expecting abc def ghi to be treated a single input, but `cin >> str2` reads one word, not one line.  To read a line, use `getline` instead:

```
getline(cin,str2);
```

Comment: Didnt help, even if the deque is outside , the loop abruplty ends without taking inputs 3 times

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem. So you see , result size increases to 3 but I should be able to give inputs 2 more times (count = 3)

Comment: And why the 2 next while loop runs without taking inputs ??

Comment: @MohitKumar: So you are expecting abc def ghi to be treated as a single input?

Comment: abc def ghi .. is one string which I want to to save in a deque in a splitted form. Yes, it is a single input.

Comment: @Mohit: Ok, you are reading using `cin >> str2`, which reads a single word, not a whole line.